# Delegate a structure in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an app to increase a little more my knowledge about swift. One of my questions if is it possible to delegate a optional function with a structure as an argument.

What yes Im able to do:

```
@objc protocol someProtocol {
    optional func optionalFunc(someClass: someClass)
}

class someClass: NSObject {

}
```

But, what I want to do (problems representing a structure in objc):

```
@objc protocol someProtocol {
    optional func optionalFunc(someStructure: someStructure)
}

struct someStructure {

}
```

And Im not able to find the way to solve this problem.

And the other thing I want, is similar to this but with enums instead of structs:

```
@objc protocol someProtocol {
    optional func optionalFunc(someEnum: someEnum)
}

enum someEnum {
    case example    
}
```

If somebody can help me, I will be very grateful!

Lot of thanks! Luciano!

Comment: Is 'someStructure' is your own defined user struct? So you need write struct in .h file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 2.0 lets you do default implementations of protocols.

```
protocol someProtocol {
    func optionalFunc(someStructure: SomeStructure)
}

extension someProtocol {
    func optionalFunc(someStructure: SomeStructure){
        // optional, leave empty
    }
}

struct SomeStructure {

}
```

This way you can get around using the optional-decoration and do what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the parameters as `struct` or `enum`, because it's only valid on Swift language, so it cannot be represented in Objective-C.

Another approach, you can declare a function as variable instead of `func`:

```
protocol someProtocol {

    var optionalFunc: (someStructure) -> ()? { get set}
}
```

Implementation:

```
class someClass : someProtocol {
    var optionalFunc: (someStructure) -> ()?  = { yourStruct in
        // Do anything with yourStruct
        return
    }
}
```

Using:

```
var someVar:someClass = someClass()
var result = someVar.optionalFunc(someStructure())
```

The result is a `()?`. If you do not implement the variable, result will `nil`